# Unable to find/import 'io.rest-assured' packages even after adding to Maven Project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, jayway

I have added the below dependencies to the maven project pom.xml file and i did a mvn clean, install. I can see the dependencies added to the .m2 folder in my c-drive/users, but they are not listed under the IntelliJ "External Libraries" section. Also when i try to import them to the class i am not seeing them and i get 'Not found' error.

Dependencies added -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because of the lack of `<scope>`. The default scope is `compile`, used if none is specified, but we need `test` here.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well i tried by adding 'scope' but it didn't work. I recreated a new project and it worked fine.